# Suppose $f : [0,1]\mapsto R$ is continuous, $f$ is differentiable on $(0,1) $and $f(0)=0$.

Tags: calculus

Assume $|f'(x)|\le |f(x)|$ for all $x\in(0,1).$ Prove that $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in[0,1]$.

I thought maybe I could use the limit but since there is no equation it won't work.

Comment: Thank you Zachary Selk for editing not use to the text conversion yet. :)

Answer (score 2):

Pick $x$ such that $|f(x)|$ reaches the maximum, then
$$
|f(x)|=\biggl|\,\int \limits_{0}^x f'(t)\, dt\,\biggr|\leq\int \limits_0^x |f'(t)|dt\leq \int\limits_{0}^x |f(t)|dt\leq x |f(x)|$$

Notice that if $|f(x)|\neq 0$ the last inequality is strict by continuity.

Answer (score 1):

The mean value theorem says that, for $x\in(0,1]$,
$$
\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=f'(\xi_x)
$$
with $\xi_x\in(0,x)$. Then
$$
|f(x)|=x|f'(\xi_x)|\le x|f(\xi_x)|
$$
Consider $y\in(0,1)$; then $|f|$ attains a maximum at $z\in(0,y]$. Then, if $|f(z)|>0$,
$$
|f(z)|=z|f'(\xi_z)|\le z|f(\xi_z)|\le z|f(z)|<|f(z)|
$$
a contradiction. Therefore the maximum of $|f|$ over each interval $[0,y]$ is zero. By continuity, also $f(1)=0$.