# Prove that f(x) vanishes in whole of its domain.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity, compactness, uniform-continuity

> $  f(x):[0,1] \to R $  is  continuous on $[0,1]$ &  differentiable on $(0,1)$ such that for all $x\in(0,1)$
>
> $$|f'(x)|\le c |f(x)|$$ for some $c\in (0,1). $  If $f(0)= 0$, prove that $f(x)=0 
>  $ on whole $[0,1]$

Here what I have done till now. Using Mean Value Theorem, 
we get $|f(x)-f(y)|= |x-y||f'(\Omega)|\le c|x-y||f(\Omega)|$  for some $\Omega\in(x,y)\subset[0,1]$.

As f is defined on compact set, so it has maxima and minima in that set. Let $M$ be maximum value of f(x) at $x_o$.

So, our inequality gives us $f(x_o) =M < f(x) + \delta |f(\mu)|$ where we choose $|x-x_o|<\delta/c$ where $\mu\in(x,x_o)$ or $(x_o,x)$ whatever suitable.

I am stuck here and not been able to proceed further. I feel like an argument like this may work : -  we can choose $\delta$ as small as possible and so equality will hold only if function must have value $M$ in an interval. As $f(0)=0$   so $M=0$

I will be grateful, if someone can provide different solutions.

Comment: Another one: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1545311/42969.

Comment: @MartinR These dupe questions assume $f'(0)$ exists, but allow $c>1$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: Unless I am mistaken, those proofs are all based on the mean-value theorem, and that requires differentiability only on the open interval.

Comment: @MartinR At least the accepted answer for https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2046696/show-that-fx-0-for-all-x-in-a-b-given-fx-leq-cfx needs that $f'$ is continouus.

Comment: Another one: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2091057/42969.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you started: $[0,1]$ is compact and $|f|$ is continuous, so let $M=\max_{x\in[0,1]}|f(x)|$ and $x_0\in[0,1]$ with $|f(x_0)|=M$. By the Mean Value Theorem, there exists $x_1\in(0,x_0)$ such that $f(x_0)-f(0)=(x_0-0)f'(x_1)$. As $f(0)=0$ and $|x_0|<1$, we get
$$ M=|f(x_0)-f(0)|=|x_0|\cdot |f'(x_1)|\le |x_0|\cdot c\cdot |f(x_1)|\le |x_0|\cdot c\cdot M.$$
If $M>0$, this implies $|x_0|\cdot c\ge 1$, but clearly $0<x_0<1$ and we are given that $0<c<1$. We conclude that $M=0$.